# Where is the location of O365 Web Add-ins in the Registry

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps, word-web-addins

**OS:** Win11 and Win10 64-bit
**Platform:** O365 (Word, Excel, Ppt, Outlook) 32-bit

How do I find the list of **WEB** Add-Ins loaded for a user?

I'm aware that COM/VSTO Add-Ins are under ..\Microsoft\Office\<application>\Addins, for example.  I'm looking for the add-ins that were sideloaded.

We are using the Desktop versions of the applications I've listed above.

Comment: The Web Add-ins are not stored in registry, they are deployed via a service and clients retrieve them from the service. A user can see their web add-ins, including admin deployed and user side-loaded from the "Get Apps" or "Get Add-ins" ribbon buttons in Outlook - not sure if this answers the question. Perhaps we could answer this better if we understood the intent of this question (i.e., what's the scenario here that you're trying to achieve).

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT  It's for troubleshooting purposes.  We routinely collect logs from a user's computer.  We have this process automated.   We'd like to be able to list the web add-ins as well to make sure that the user is running the add-ins that we want them to, and that they're using the right version.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand why this is necessary, could you help clarify? Tenant admins have control over add-ins their users can run, and depending on deployment path, the version of an add-in is also either controlled by admin, or automatically updated by the system.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT
It's a business process.  We want to know what is loaded on our user machines.  Think of it as inventory.   Things don't always turn out the way and admin anticipates.   How would you recommend I approach this?  Is there a recommended way that this information can be retrieved?

Comment: I'd recommend describing your requirement and posting it on Tech Community Page (https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions), where we track Outlook add-in feature requests. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I've made a post on the suggested page.  The answer received was a Powershell solution.  I was hoping for C#, but this will have to suffice for now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook, the list of web addins is currently (AFAIK it was changed a few times) stored in a hidden (associated) message in the Inbox folder. The message class is "`IPM.Configuration.ExtensionMasterTable"` - you should be able to open that message using `MAPIFolder.GetStorage`. The XML is stored in the `PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7C080102"`) MAPI property.

You can see the XML blob in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if go to the Inbox folder in Outlook, click IMAPIFolder button, go to "Associated Contacts" tab, locate the message with the message class given above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks AGAIN, Dmitry.   I'll look into this ASAP.  We're big user's of Redemption and OutlookSpy.

Comment: I wasn't sure where to run MAPIFolder.GetStorage from, so I double clicked on "IPM.Configuration.ExtensionMasterTable".   PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM looks to be the answer!!!   I will mark it as such.   Thanks again.     I'll see if I can use Redemption to get this information.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is internal implementation detail that can, and likely will, change. Generally, I would discourage from taking such dependencies, it will make your solutions fragile.

Comment: Yes, that is why I noted "AFAIK it was changed a few times". In the absence of am officially supported API from Microsoft, that is the best we can do. This is not the first time this topic comes up - a COM addin needs to know if a particular web addin is installed and vice versa.